# Creating html results from tests generated dynamically

Tags: python, html, python-unittest

I am using in my project implementation of test generator from [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/04/02/dynamically-generating-python-test-cases)

This simply generates test cases on the base of data (amount of data) that i provide to test_function.

I am trying to generate HTML output from that to a file i.e 'report.html'

```
import unittest


class DynamicClassBase(unittest.TestCase):
    longMessage = True


def make_test_function(description, a, b):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(a, b, description)
    return test


def main():
    testsmap = {
        'foo': [1, 1],
        'bar': [1, 2],
        'baz': [5, 5]}

    for name, params in testsmap.iteritems():
        test_func = make_test_function(name, params[0], params[1])
        klassname = 'Test_{0}'.format(name)
        globals()[klassname] = type(klassname,
                                    (DynamicClassBase,),
                                    {'test_gen_{0}'.format(name): test_func})

    unittest.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have found a nice way to generate it using [HTMLTestRunner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html) but i had problems combining this two solutions. 
The main problem is that HTMLTestRunner gets a suite `suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(classname)` as a parameter

Sample HTMLTestRunner that I use:

```
import HTMLTestRunner
import unittest

def main():
    class htmlreportsdemo(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_pass(self):
            pass

        def test_fail(self):
            self.fail()


suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(htmlreportsdemo)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
output = open("results.html", "w")
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=output, title='demo title',
                                       description='demo desc')
runner.run(suite)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i've got some solution based on extension of `suite` that i pass to a `runner`.

Hope someone find it usefull:

```
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

class DynamicClassBase(unittest.TestCase):
    longMessage = True


def make_test_function(description, a, b):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(a, b, description)
    return test


def main():
    tests_classes = []   # container for generated test classes
    testsmap = {
        'foo': [1, 1],
        'bar': [1, 2],
        'baz': [5, 5]}

    for name, params in testsmap.iteritems():
        test_func = make_test_function(name, params[0], params[1])
        klassname = 'Test_{0}'.format(name)
        globals()[klassname] = type(klassname,
                                    (DynamicClassBase,),
                                    {'test_gen_{0}'.format(name): test_func})
        test_classes_to_run.append(globals()[klassname])

    # solution starts here: 
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suites_list = []
    for test_class in test_classes_to_run:
        suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)
        suites_list.append(suite)

    big_suite = unittest.TestSuite(suites_list)
    with open('results.html', 'w') as html_file:
        runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=html_file,
                                           verbosity=2,
                                           title='demo title',
                                           description='demo descr')
        runner.run(big_suite)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

class DynamicClassBase(unittest.TestCase):
    longMessage = True

def make_method(name, a, b):
    def _method(self, a=a, b=b):
        self.assertEqual(a, b, name)
    return _method

def main():
    tests_map = {
        'foo': [1, 1],
        'bar': [1, 2],
        'baz': [5, 5]
    }
    for name, params in tests_map.iteritems():
        test_name = "test_gen_%s" % name
        _method = make_method(test_name, params[0], params[1])
        setattr(DynamicClassBase, test_name, _method)
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(DynamicClassBase)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    with open('results.html', 'w') as html_file:
        runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=html_file,
                                               title='demo title',
                                               description='demo descr')
        runner.run(suite)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

NOTE: This solution uses default parameters to get the values into the test functions.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty close to what i am looking for. The only thing to fix is that `setattr` makes all generated tests originating from `(__main__.DynamicClassBase)` and in my fist example each test comes from its own "class": `(__main__.Test_foo)` etc. In current solution if one of test's is failed, its reported as  a whole class failed, and not as desired: separate test case. But thank's anyway, this was a good hint for a starter!